# No Adapter Attached; Skipping Layout when using retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, apiclient

This is how I'm setting up my Recycler view in my Search Fragment. I don't understand why I keep getting the same error and what I'm missing.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
    searchText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.searchText);
    searchButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
    nutritionRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.nutritionRecyclerView);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
            ApiClient.getInstance().getNutritionApiAdapter()
                    .getSearchResults(
                            AppDefines.APPLICATION_ID,
                            AppDefines.APPLICATION_KEY,
                            searchText.getText().toString())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Observer<SearchResultsModel>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(SearchResultsModel searchResultsModel) {

                            // On handling the http response, instantiate a new adapter with the results
                            adapter = new NutritionAdapter(searchResultsModel.getSearchResults());

                            adapter.setOnItemSelected(new NutritionAdapter.OnItemSelected() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSelected(NutritionItemModel item) {
                                    if (onFragmentEvent != null) {
                                        onFragmentEvent.onEvent(item);
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                            // Assigning the LayoutManager to the RecyclerView
                            nutritionRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                            // Assigning the Adapter to the RecyclerView. If this isn't done, the view will not populate
                            nutritionRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                    });
        }
   });




    return view;
}
```

Here is my ApiClient
    public class ApiClient {
    private static ApiClient instance;

```
public static ApiClient getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new ApiClient();
    }

    return instance;
}

public NutritionApiAdapter getNutritionApiAdapter() {
    NutritionApiAdapter api = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(AppDefines.BASE_API_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(NutritionApiAdapter.class);

    return api;
}
}
```

And this is my NutritionApiAdapter

```
public interface NutritionApiAdapter {
@GET("item")
Observable<SearchResultsModel> getSearchResults(
        @Query("_app_id") String appId,
        @Query("_app_key") String appKey,
        @Query("q") String searchString);
}
```

NutritionAdpater

```
public class NutritionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NutritionItemViewHolder>{


private ArrayList<NutritionItemModel> nutritionItemCollection;
private OnItemSelected onItemSelected;

public NutritionAdapter(ArrayList<NutritionItemModel> nutritionItemCollection){
    this.nutritionItemCollection = nutritionItemCollection;
}


@Override
public NutritionItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_nutrition, parent, false);
    return new NutritionItemViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NutritionItemViewHolder holder,int position) {
    NutritionItemModel item = nutritionItemCollection.get(position);
    holder.setOnRecipeItemClicked(new NutritionItemViewHolder.OnNutritionItemClicked(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(NutritionItemModel item) {
            if(onItemSelected != null) {
                onItemSelected.onSelected(item);
            }
        }
    });

    // Bind the RecipeItemModel data to the view managed by the ViewHolder
    holder.bind(item);
}

@Override
public final void onViewRecycled(final NutritionItemViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
    holder.setOnRecipeItemClicked(null);
    holder.unbind();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {return nutritionItemCollection.size();}

public void setOnItemSelected(OnItemSelected onItemSelected) {
    this.onItemSelected = onItemSelected;
}
public interface OnItemSelected {
    void onSelected(NutritionItemModel item);
}

}
```

and NutritionItemViewHolder

```
 public class NutritionItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
private TextView foodName;
private ImageView foodThumbnail;
private NutritionItemModel item;
private TextView item_name;
private TextView brand_name;
private OnNutritionItemClicked onNutritionItemClicked;

//todo add other elements here

public NutritionItemViewHolder(final View itemView) {super(itemView);}

public final void bind(final NutritionItemModel item) {

    item_name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
    brand_name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.brand_name);


    //foodThumbnail = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodThumbnail);
    //todo add other element id things here

    /*
    //used for preloading images
    Glide.with(itemView.getContext())
            .load(item.getSmallImageUrls().get(0))
            .into(foodThumbnail);
        */

    item_name.setText(item.getFields().getItem_name());
    brand_name.setText(item.getFields().getBrand_name());
}

public final void unbind() {
    //todo ?
    //For later with butterknife
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(onNutritionItemClicked != null) {
        onNutritionItemClicked.onClick(item);
    }
}

// The setter that allows other classes to create a reference to the listener.
public void setOnRecipeItemClicked(OnNutritionItemClicked onNutritionItemClicked) {
    this.onNutritionItemClicked = onNutritionItemClicked;
}

// An interface is added as an internal implementation in our ViewHolder.  This will allow
// classes that instantiate a new instance of this ViewHolder to subscribe to this interface
// and listen for events.
public interface OnNutritionItemClicked {
    void onClick(NutritionItemModel item);
}

}
```

Comment: Can you paste your error here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the layoutmanager,

```
LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
list.setLayoutManager(llm);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Maybe this can help you.